# Spark with Hive : Table or view not found

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

> ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: "DB_X"."table_Y"

Spark session :

```
  SparkSession
    .builder()          
    .appName(appName)
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/apps/hive/warehouse")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate();
```

Hive warehouse directory in hive-site.xml : /apps/hive/warehouse/

```
hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/
drwxrwxrwx   - root hadoop          0 2018-09-03 11:22 /apps/hive/warehouse/DB_X.db


hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/DB_X.db
none
```

Error is throw here :

```
spark
   .read()
   .table("DB_X.table_Y");
```

in java :

```
spark.sql("show databases").show()
default
```

in spark-shell interactive :

```
spark.sql("show databases").show()
default
DB_X
```

show create table table_Y :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table_Y`(
...
PARTITIONED BY (
  `partition` string COMMENT '')
...
    location '/data/kafka-connect/topics/table_Y'
```

hadoop files :

```
hadoop fs -ls /data/kafka-connect/topics/table_Y
drwxr-xr-x   - kafka hdfs          0 2018-09-11 17:24 /data/kafka-connect/topics/table_Y/partition=0
drwxr-xr-x   - kafka hdfs          0 2018-09-11 17:24 /data/kafka-connect/topics/table_Y/partition=1

hadoop fs -ls data/kafka-connect/topics/table_Y/partition=0
-rw-r--r--   3 kafka hdfs     102388 2018-09-11 17:24 /data/kafka-connect/topics/table_Y/partition=0/table_Y+0+0001823382+0001824381.avro
-rw-r--r--   3 kafka hdfs     102147 2018-09-11 17:24 /data/kafka-connect/topics/table_Y/partition=0/table_Y+0+0001824382+0001825381.avro
...
```

everythings work fine in spark-shell or hive-shell

hive-site.xml from hive conf is copied in spark2/conf

using HDP 2.6.4.0-91 with spark 2.2

any help ?

Comment: Make sure you have **copied hive-site.xml** into **/etc/spark2/conf** directory **cp /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml /etc/spark2/conf** then restart spark2 service, Try to read the data from the table.

Comment: Can you select from your table in spark-sql? or for instance in spark-shell `spark.sql("select * from DB_X.table_Y limit 10")`

Comment: also try `spark.sql("show tables in DB_X")`

Comment: @Shu hive-site.xml was already copied in spark2/conf and it workd from spark-shell and hive shell .

Comment: @serge_k yes everythings work fine from spark-shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

relocating the table using the HA name solve the problem.